# How to undo .click(false)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page transition which uses jQuery animate. I found that the following code:

```
$("body").click(false);
```

is the best way to stop any mouse clicks on the page while the animation is running. But I'm not sure how to undo it! Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for `:animated` length on body click.try this:

```
$('body').click(function () {
if ($(':animated').length) {
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: So every time there's a click, filter every single element in the document to see if it matches the `:animated` selector?

Comment: @cookiemonster:that way you prevent binding unbindig of event on every animation.

Comment: Thanks bro, such a simple yet effective method!

Comment: Binding and unbinding on every animation will be much faster than running Sizzle on every element on the page every time there's a click. That's going to basically do `var els = document.getElementsByTagName("*")` and pass the entire collection to `Sizzle` to run the custom `:animated` selector.

Comment: ...if there's only one element being animated, then that element should be the one tested. That wouldn't be a bad solution.

Answer (score 3):

Try using [.unbind()](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)

```
$("body").unbind("click");
```

Comment: Pass `false` as the second argument to unbind the specific handler that was bound with `$("body").click(false);`

Answer (score 0):

show me the animation code snippet. You should place $("body").unbind("click"); in the callback of the animation function. When it's done animating, it will unbind the click again.